# jpeg image memory size compared to ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a jpeg image. The size is 227 437 bytes. But when I convert it to a ndarray it is much bigger.

Could someone tell why the ndarray is much bigger please ?

When I import it like that

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = np.array(Image.open('image.jpg'))
print(im.nbytes)
```

I see : 4 320 000 bytes. So approximately 20 times the size of the image.

Comment: What does `im.dtype` show?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that images are compressed and when you convert it to a numpy array you no longer have that compression.

Comment: The dtype is dtype('uint8').

Comment: So 8-bit numbers (i.e. 1 byte). I'd guess the dimensions are (m,n,3) where `m*n = 1440000` (alternatively, `np.prod(im.shape) == 4320000`). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct but I still don't understand why there is a difference between the size of the image and the ndarray.

Comment: Because numpy stores all the data while the image file is compressed (it uses a more efficient encoding to reduce the file size).